# Flash is turning off, when starting video recording using Camera2 api

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-debug

I am using two capture session one is previewSession() and second is recordingSession()

```
private fun previewSession() {
    val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture
    MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = textureView.height
    MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = textureView.width

    surfaceTexture?.setDefaultBufferSize(MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH)
    val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
    captureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)


    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
        listOf(surface),
        object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                if (session != null) {
                    captureSession = session
                    captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                        captureRequestBuilder.build(),
                        null,
                        null
                    )

                }
            }

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                showLog(TAG, "Failed to create CameraCaptureSession")
            }
        },
        mBackgroundHandler
    )
}
```

And the recordingSesion() is like:

```
private fun recordSession() {
    setUpMediaRecorder()
    val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture
    MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = textureView.height
    MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = textureView.width

    surfaceTexture?.setDefaultBufferSize(MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH)
    val textureSurface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
    val recordSurface = mediaRecorder.surface
    captureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD)
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(textureSurface)
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface)

    val surfaces = ArrayList<Surface>().apply {
        add(textureSurface)
        add(recordSurface)
    }

    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
        surfaces,
        object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                captureSession = session
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                    captureRequestBuilder.build(),
                    null,
                    null
                )
                isRecording = true
                mediaRecorder.start()
            }

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                showLog(TAG, "Failed to create CameraRecordSession!")
            }

        },
        mBackgroundHandler
    )
}
```

And the toggleFlash method to turn on/off the Flash.

```
fun toggleFlashState(view: View) {
        if (isFlashOn) {
                captureRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF
                )
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                isFlashOn = false
        } else {
                captureRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                    CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
                )
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                isFlashOn = true
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I am turning on the flash and starting the recording, the flash is getting turn off. Can anyone help me with how can I turn on the flash permanently so that the flash will not turn off automatically? It should turn off and on by invoking the toggleFlash() method only.

Comment: According to docs, Auto exposure must be either ON or OFF. Otherwise, AutoExposure (ae) will override the flash mode setting

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be that you're overwriting your old captureRequestBuilder whenever you call recordSession (or previewSession). So whatever changes the last call to toggleFlashState did to the captureRequestBuilder will be lost at that point.

So in recordSession and previewSession, you need to look at the value of isFlashOn, and set the FLASH_MODE to the right value after you create the new request builder.

Comment: I tried the same with the help of isFlashOn boolean, but whenever a new session is building the flash built with the previous session is getting turned off and flash with the new session is turning on. Due to this, a blink is occuring. Flash is not permanently turned on. Do you have any suggestion on it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's device-specific behavior, and it's probably be pretty common that the flash turns off during session creation.  There's not likely any workaround for this.

Comment: No, it is not. You can check the behaviour in the native cameras. The flash remains on, if we turn it on before the  recording.

Comment: Yes, they will have already created the recording output at the start of recording mode.   Not when recording actually starts.  I assumed you didn't want to do that.  Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#createPersistentInputSurface() in particular.